# Runtime/Logical error with a binary flipper

Tags: binary, freepascal

So I'm currently working on a school project with a bunch of binary, 2s complement and other base conversions. Part of what i'm working on is a binary flipper; 1 becomes 0 and 0 becomes 1. I've written it as a function taking in and returning a string.

```
function flipbit(inp:string) : string;
var
  new : string;
  x:integer;

begin

writeln('new: ',new);
writeln('inp: ',inp);
new := '';
writeln('new assigned');
for x:= 1 to length(inp) do;

  begin
     writeln('loop started');
     if strtoint(inp[x]) = 1 then
      begin
        new := new + '0';
        writeln('0 added');
      end;

 if strtoint(inp[x]) = 0 then
  begin
    new := new + '1';
    writeln('1 added');
  end
  else
  begin
    writeln('Something went wrong');
  end;
end;

result := new;


end;
```

Basically the code iterates through a string of 1s and 0s, and re-writes them in another string but flips the bits.

I've used strtoint of inp[x] (inp is the input variable) and compared it to 1 (As an integer not a string)
I originally just tried comparing inp[x] without integer conversion to '1'. The code compiled, but 'new' did not change at all.
When I tried the method I'm using right now, the code crashes.

I've used debug writeln statements to try and narrow down where exactly the code is going wrong and it seems to be the if statement.

If anyone could help, that would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you receive as an array of integers and operate a not operation in each position? It has to be a string?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert chars to integers. You don't need to declare a local variable since you already have the 'result' variable.

```
function flipbit(inp: string): string;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := inp;
  for i := 1 to Length(result) do
    if result[i] = '0' then
      result[i] := '1'
    else
      if result[i] = '1' then  
        result[i] := '0';
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

```
function flipbit(inp: string): string;
const
  OTHER_VALUE: array['0'..'1'] of char = ('1', '0');
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := inp;
  for i := 1 to Length(result) do
    if result[i] in ['0', '1'] then
      result[i] := OTHER_VALUE[result[i]];
end;
```